# sum by groups in KDB

Tags: kdb

I have a PnL table with 3 columns. date, region, product.

I'm trying to group all PnL rows by region and product. One way that i've tried is to sum by region and product as following

select PnL : sum(PnL) by region, product from table where date within (d1;d2)

The issue I have is unexpected results. For a given date range (d1;d2) I'm getting the results I'm expecting. However for date range (d1;d2+1) I'm getting 0 everywhere.

I checked the data availability on the d2+1 and data is already available on that day.

Please note that the server is stateless and it is not possible to use intermediate results in variables.

What is the best way to achieve a grouping sum in KDB?

Comment: Can you replicate the problem with a small sample table and provide that here? When I tried your expression in the REPL it worked fine. (The parens aren’t needed around PnL but that made no difference.)

Comment: it will be difficult to tell what the issue is without the db itself. Have you looked at what your query is returning for just d2+1.

Comment: Is it possible that your sum is overflowing the maximum value of the datatype? For example if your pnl column is an integer type column then it's going to overflow when the sum reaches ~2bn. Though this wouldn't result in zeros as you say, it would result in large negative numbers.

Comment: @MattMoore yes I did., and  data are available for that date. More precisely, the query fails only when the end date range  is the last available business date (which contains data as mentioned).

Comment: the only case I've seen where you get weird behavior with a select is with a segmented db but this is not the case in this instance as from testing I did not reproduce the issue.